# Making PDFs readable on my eReader

Tags: pdf, editing, ereader

I have a bunch of PDF documents/books that I would like to read on my eReader.
[The one I have](http://www.bol.com/nl/p/elektronica/sony-reader-pocket-edition-zilver/9000000006931121/index.html) supports the PDFs and even allows showing tophalf/bottomhalf when used in landscape orientation.

The problem is that even in landscape mode the font is really small.
So I press the 'zoom'/'font size' button and the text gets bigger .... and to code examples, diagrams, etc. become too messed up to be useful.

The thing with these PDFs is that they have been created with "printing" in mind. So the pages have a layout that is consistent with a specific paper format. With many of these documents this format includes about 2.5 cm of white margin on all 4 sides of each page.

What I would like to try is to see if these PDFs become readable on this device if I cut off this white border. I have several documents with several hundred pages each and I'm a bit too lazy to do each page manually.

What tool can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** claims to be a one stop solution to all your e-book needs.

Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, EPUB, FB2, HTML, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, **PDF**, PRC**, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, TXT

Output Formats: **EPUB**, FB2, OEB, LIT, **LRF**, MOBI, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, TXT

[image]

*Calibre is freeware (and can be used portable, check their forum)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I have not been able to find the option I was looking for. Converting into a different format (like epub) resulted in corrupted code examples and graphics. Very similar as the reader would product.